# SpriteKit physicsBody always upright

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have a spritenode with a physics body that is affected by gravity and dynamic, however, when it hits things it rotates.

I am only using the physicsbody for the Y axis gravity, and nothing else. When it hits something horizontally, I don't want it to be affected by that thing..

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight from the Sprite kit programming guide:

**The allowsRotation property determines whether forces can impart angular velocity on the body.**

Comment: I guess I should have looked harder. Thanks.